# Alert when dynamic value is greater a number

Tags: excel, vba, notifications, alert

I'm looking for a way for excel to alert me when a dynamic value (market feed data) is out of line by x%. The alert needs to appear in front of all my windows with a msg box "CHECK VALUES".

Is this possible to do and has anyone have an example of code for this?

More specifically

```
Minimum difference = 0.5

CELL A = 10
CELL B = 11
Difference = 1

ALERT user "Difference > 0.5"
```

Thank you in advance.

Thank you. This works perfect. Now I understand how it works, I'm hoping for another solution similar to the above. Both cells in A1 and B1 are constantly changing(variables). Cell C1 is the =ABS(B1-A1). What I need now is a code to alert me when Cell C1 is greater than 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `worksheet_change` event. Try below code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo err_rout

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Address = "$A$1" And Target.CountLarge = 1 Then

        If (Target.Value - Target.Offset(0, 1)) > 0.5 Then
            MsgBox "CHECK VALUES"
        End If
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$B$1" And Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
        If (Target.Value - Target.Offset(0, -1)) > 0.5 Then
            MsgBox "CHECK VALUES"
        End If
    End If


err_rout:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this but could you please a little more how it should work?

Comment: Could you explain what is meant to occur? I copied in the code and modified cells A1 and B1. However, no alert/msgbox is appearing. My cells values are 20 and 10. This should definitely show the msgbox.

Comment: @user3006730 please copy the code in sheet code section. I have added an image in the answer. Let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfect. Now I understand how it works, I'm hoping for another solution similar to the above. Both cells in A1 and B1 are constantly changing(variables). Cell C1 is the =ABS(B1-A1). What I need now is a code to alert me when Cell C1 is greater than 0.5.

Comment: @user3006730 Use this `If Target.Address = "$C$1" And Target.CountLarge = 1 Then If (Target.Value > 0.5) Then MsgBox "CHECK VALUES" End If End If`

Comment: I tried the new solution however, when the Cell C1 changes due to Cells A1 or B2, no msgbox alert appears. If I manually change C1 to a value > 0.5, then the alert appears. Any reason why it doesn't work?